# I'm not sure where I made a mistake here, i'm currently using tweepy, python and working with the twitter api

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I was working on quick replies for twitter dms, using tweepy and python, however i came across an issue.

```
def dm():
    followers = api.followers()
    for follower in followers:
        print(follower.id)
        reply_options = [
                {
                        "label": "A title test",
                        "description": "Just a description test",
                        "metadata": "external_id_1"
                },
                {
                        "label": "A title test 2",
                        "description": "Test Description 2",
                        "metadata": "external_id_2"

                }
        ]
        api.send_direct_message(follower.id,"Text", quick_reply_type="options",quick_reply_options = reply_options)
```

And I was met with this output:

```
File "c:/Users/Azizah Blackwood/Documents/GitHub/just-a-chatbot-test/chatBot.py", line 58, in <module>
    dm()
  File "c:/Users/Azizah Blackwood/Documents/GitHub/just-a-chatbot-test/chatBot.py", line 54, in dm
    api.send_direct_message(follower.id,"Text", quick_reply_type="options",quick_reply_options = reply_options)
TypeError: send_direct_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quick_reply_options'
```

I was following through what I read [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1280) to add options to test if it would work.

Comment: That patch ([#1364](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1364)) which implements this is not yet merged into the main tweepy source. That means it isn't available to use yet. If you need it, you may want to build it from source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quick_reply_options` is not in current version of tweepy: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1364

It may be added later, but for now, you need to stay within the params of the current version.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.